# 1950-60s children's book about a boy whose neighbor builds a spaceship and he flies it to outer space

Tags: spaceship, childrens-novel

The older, male, neighbor was key - Mr. ?somebody? actually started building the spaceship in his garage or a shed. One book might have been "Something in Outer Space"? Neighbor might have smoked a pipe, the spaceship might have resembled a go-cart.  There were subsequent books.  It was not the Dolph books.

I remember the descriptions of taking off, going up through the atmosphere - it had me completely enraptured.  I'm guessing it was late 50s or 60s?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Great first question, thank you for including the rough date and some extra details. If you can think of anything else please do add it in, and while we have you please do checkout out the [help] and take out [tour]! Share and enjoy!

Comment: Sounds like even if they aren’t the books you’re thinking of you might enjoy *Rocket Ship Galileo* and *Have Spacesuit, Will Travel* by Robert Heinlein.

Comment: I wonder it is might be "The Wonderful flight to the Mushroom Planet". There the children built the rocket and the adult helped, which is a big difference with the question though.

Comment: @Clara You may have it, because IIRC, Mr. Bass smoked a pipe.

Comment: @MaidenShade  So what are the "Dolph books" that the book you ask about is not one of?

Comment: @MaidenShade  To me this book seems like it could be a combination of Rusty's Spaceship, The Wonderful flight to the Mushroom Planet, and possibly a bit of Rocket Ship Gallileo.  So possibly your membory is combining two or more separate books, or possibly the book you are asking about is one I never read.

Comment: If the book is Wonderful flight to the Mushroom Planet, by Eleanor Cameron, you can borrow a copy online at Archive.org. There is a related book Stowaway to the Mushroom Planet by the same author. Both books were written in the 1950s. I recall reading them, they were fun, have no recollection if they have the story you are seeking. Have Spacesuit Will Travel was the first science fiction book I ever read, and even re-reading recently, it still holds up as a great story.

Comment: In the Mushroom Planet books the ship was on a wheeled carriage that they pushed it out of the garage on. Maybe that's the go-cart?

Comment: In the first Mushroom Planet book, the boys built the physical structure of the ship in a cave near the beach, then pulled it on a wheeled cart to Mr. Bass's house. Mr. Bass put the ship in his basement(?) workshop, and put sealant on it, and installed the mechanisms and fuel tank. That covers some of the points you remember. One 'outer spacey' title in that series was "Mr. Bass's Planetoid."